# How to delete the content that are out of a div size

Tags: css, blazor

I have a parent div with a certain size and inside him I have other divs and if any of those child divs start showing their content out of the parent div I want to delete that div, and no I don't want to put it hidden with the overflow I really want to delete him. I tried to search the solution but I didn't found any. How can I manage this problem?

I have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwjroaue/1/) to a better understading the problem.

Here is the code:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 55px; background-color: gray">
  <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  <div style="border: 2px solid red">
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <strong>I WANT DO DELETE THIS DIV!</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know if I can do this with Blazor but I'm here to learn.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: CSS alone can not do this, you’d have to involve JS to loop over child elements and check their position and dimensions. // In your example, the first child just happens to be the same height as the whole parent container. What would you like to happen if that was not the case? If it was slightly _higher_, would you want to remove _all_ children then?

Comment: Do u want to delete the inner div?

Comment: @misorude I did this examle because is simple but if my first div had a letter out of the parent div yes I want to delete that div.

Comment: @Manikandan2811 yes I want to delete the inner divs that are out of the parent div, in this case, the second one, but I want a solution that work if would be 2 or more divs.

Comment: Do u want to delete the entire inner div except first div? Is this correct?

Comment: @Manikandan2811 In this case, yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can do this by looping over the children, and checking if their top corner is “higher” on the Y axis (“higher” value on that axis meaning, it is lower down on the screen), than the parent’s own height. You can use the `offsetTop` property here, *if* the parent element is also the `offsetParent` of the children - if positioning is involved anywhere, that might change the offsetParent, so in that case you might need to work with coordinates relative to the viewport.

```js
var p = document.getElementById('parent'),
    c = p.children;

for(var i=c.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
  console.log(c[i], c[i].offsetTop, p.offsetHeight)
  if(c[i].offsetTop >= p.offsetHeight || c[i].offsetHeight > p.offsetHeight) {
    p.removeChild(c[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
#parent { position: relative; }
```

```html
foo
<br>
<div id="parent" style="width: 300px; height: 55px; background-color: gray">
  <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  <div style="border: 2px solid red">
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <strong>I WANT DO DELETE THIS DIV!</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am looping over the children in reverse order here - that gives less hassle with removing elements, and the index of the remaining elements in the live HTMLCollection returned by `children`.

I introduced the `foo<br>` at the beginning here, so that the whole element is set off a bit from the viewport - then you’ll notice how setting the parent to `position:relative` changes the offsetTop values, remove that from the CSS and see how the values in the debug output change.

Now this is a trivial way to do this, based on your rather trivial example. In more complex layout situations, it might not work that easily.

---

Edit: Need to check not only the offsetTop, but the offsetHeight as well. Otherwise, the last element might not get removed, if it is higher than the parent itself.

Comment: If you needed this on the X axis as well, things will get more complicated. In that case, the children will likely not extend beyond the width of the parent themselves (unless you explicitly specified a width for them), but their own content will overflow them in turn.

Comment: No I don't need the X cause if they are bigger they automatically go to the bottom line. Thank you!

Comment: How this answer is related to Blazor ? Your solution don't even attempt to suggest a way to do it in  Blazor, one way or another ...

Comment: @Issac it isn’t, and I didn’t pretend it was. Feel free to do a rewrite, if you are familiar with Blazor - I’m not. But I guess it should provide a way to execute such custom code snippets somehow.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a css attribute overflow : hidden

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: As I said I don't want to hidden them I want do delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.. Try this code..

**css**

```
div div:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I want a flexible solution. A solution that verify if the inner div content is out of the parent div and then delete it.

Comment: I could'nt clear ur concept? can u plz explain clearly?

Comment: So imagine if I change the div contents and my second div doesn't go out of the parent div your solution will not be correct for that. Im looking for something to verify if the inner divs is or not out of parent div if it is delete those who are out of the parent div.